# Casting on run-time in C#

Tags: c#, java, class, generics, inheritance

When I wanted a generic object extended from a class, in Java I used to write:

```
Class<AuthenticationProvider> c1;
```

What am I supposed to write in C# to do the same? How can I cast a Type Class Object in this format (a generic class extended from Authentication provider)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [`Type.MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx)?

---

#### Edit:

Oops, I see what you mean now. No, you *can't* do this in C#, because `System.Type` is *not* a generic type! It contains information *about* a type, but there's nothing generic about it, so `typeof(Foo)` does not give you `Type<Foo>`.

I don't see why you'd need it either, though.

Comment: Because I get a Type object as a return parameter; I'd like to convert this type to a generic class which extends Authentication provider

Comment: @Dharma: Like I said, that doesn't make any sense in C#, because `Type` is *not generic*. What is the reason for doing this? Maybe we could provide a better solution for the problem you're facing.

Comment: I am porting an application from Java to C#, and I have plenty of methods which return objects of run-time created classes, like Class<AuthenticationProvider> or Class<? Extends AuthenticationProvider>...is there a way to to this in C#? Is there a "Class" keyword for C#?

Comment: @Dharma: Do you mean `typeof(Foo)`?

Comment: No, I mean something like:

Class<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviderClass =
                    (Class<AuthenticationProvider>)Configuration.getInstance().getAuthenticationProviderClass();

where from the method getAuthenticationProviderClass I get a Class Object

Comment: @Dharma: The `Class` class in Java is pretty much the same thing as `System.Type` in C#, and `Foo.class` is pretty much the same thing as `typeof(Foo)` in C#. I'm not sure if that answers your question, though.

Comment: Do you absolutely need the genericness of `Class<?>`? If not, `Type` is what you need and should be sufficient.

Comment: As I said before I am porting a java application; this application has a module which return a Class Object (in my app it returns a Type Object); then I need to convert this in an AuthenticationProvider class or in a generic class extended from AuthenticationProvider. Is it clear? How could I do this?

Comment: @Dharma Dude - As already been explained what you want is unrealstic with C#.  Your going to have to design it different in C# then you would in Java that is the simple fact.  Considering revision your question with some actual code.